# Curl to Laravel results in redirect

Tags: php, curl, laravel-4, laravel-5

When I make a cURL request to my Laravel route, instead of just returning back the content of the process, it actually redirect me to the homepage, returning this HTML

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://erm.gratuz.net.com/api/requesthandler" />
  <title>Redirecting to http://erm.gratuz.net.com/api/requesthandler</title>
 </head>
 <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://erm.gratuz.net.com/api/requesthandler">http://erm.gratuz.net.com/api/requesthandler</a>.
 </body>
</html>
```

My cURL request is as follows:

```
$url =  "http://erm.gratuz.net.com/api/requesthandler/";
$session = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $session, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
curl_setopt( $session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields );
$response = curl_exec( $session );
curl_close( $session );
```

Below is the routes accepting post as well

```
Route::any('/api/requesthandler', 'TestController@requesthandler');
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Running into the same issue - wondering if you ever found out what was going on?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't - I pointed my curl request to a page not controlled by Laravel.

Answer (score 4):

You can follow redirects in your curl up to 5 layers deep if you use:

```
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Then if the page you curl redirect, your curl will return the data from the page it redirects to instead of what you are currently seeing.

Comment: When I do that, I end up at the home page of my Laravel set up

Comment: sounds like an .htaccess redirect issue or some internal redirection that is trying to load your data into a template instead of just providing the JSON string. I am not familiar with Laravel, I would suggest changing your url to not have the trailing slash as Artsemis suggested and see if that works. If that does not work, see if there is some GET variable you need to set to get raw data not loaded into a template.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with Laravel 5.2. In my case it was happening because of `TokenMismatchException`. Adding the particular route to the CSRF verification exception list solved the issue for me.

In `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

```
protected $except = [
    'your route here'
];
```

Comment: Yes! Or put that route in api.php instead of web.php. There's no CSRF token verification for the routes in api.php.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect is taking you to http://erm.gratuz.net.com/api/requesthandler but your cURL call is going to http://erm.gratuz.net.com/api/requesthandler/ -- I assume the redirect is Laravel stripping the trailing slash.

Comment: No, the problem is that it should actually return the content for http://erm.gratuz.net/api/requesthandler, not this html output with a javascript redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable http_only in your laravel project
file: session.php

`http_only => false,`